# How to read n numbers separated by space in C

Tags: c, arrays, input, scanf

I want to read `n` integers from user during execution and the numbers are separated by spaces. It would be the best to be received as an array. For input `1 22 3 445 3`, the result is, `array[0]=1`, `array[1]=22` and so on. I have to do it in C. Can't use

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &var1, &var2, &var3);
```

because, I don't know how many such numbers would be inserted. The value of `n` would be read from user just before reading this data.

Comment: Have you heard about loops?

Comment: I don't think loops can be used to read numbers separated by space, on the same line. It require different statement for each value for a loop to run, right? Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: If you don't know how many elements you can use `fgets` and `strtol` in a loop, you can use a fixed length array like `int arr[MAX_ELEMS];` to store those values, or `realloc`, or a linked list ... there are several ways.

Comment: @NirmalScaria You Can

Answer (score 2):

Use [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) and then [strtok()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) with [atoi()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm).

Take the numbers as a string.

Here is one way to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  char numbers[100];
  int myn[100];
  printf("Give me numbers..\n");
  fgets(numbers,100,stdin);
  const char s[2] = " ";
  char *token;

  token = strtok(numbers, s);
  int i=0;    
  myn[i]=atoi(token);

  while( token != NULL ) 
  {
    i++;
    printf( " %s\n", token );
    token = strtok(NULL, s);
    myn[i]=atoi(token);
  }
  printf("You gave me: ");
  for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
    printf ("%d, ", myn[j]);
  }
  return(0);
}
```

The above C program does exactly what you want. At the for loop, it prints to the screen the numbers you gave from keyboard. The "problem" would be much easier by using *enter* instead of *spaces* between the numbers.

[image: givenumbers.c]

---

Click on the links, to see very useful details about the functions used.

Comment: But we need to convert those strings to `int` using something like `atoi` or `strtol`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes; after using `strtok` to split the string into individual values, you would use such a function to convert the individual value strings into `int`s.

Comment: There's no need to use `strtok()`; using `strtol()` would be better.  It tells you where the end of each converted number is; it also does range checking, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
enum { MAX_NUMBERS = 1000000 };  // Choose appropriate upper bound
int n;
if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n > 0 && n < MAX_NUMBERS)
{
    int array[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1)
            …process error — terminate loop?…
    }
    …use array…
}
```

You can read multiple numbers with `scanf()` using a loop as shown.  You've no idea whether they were all presented on a single line, or each was on its own line, or whether there were many blank lines between successive numbers (or any permutation of all these possibilities).

The `scanf()` family of functions basically do not care about newlines — it is hard to force them to do so.  When you care about line-based input, use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read a line and [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) — or other string parsing functions — to process the line.

I'm assuming support for C99 with VLA (variable length arrays).  The principles are the same without that support — the mechanics are a little different (and there are multiple options for how to do it).